# Using CaCErt to certificate java applet

Tags: java, applet

I'm using CaCert (www.cacert.org) to certificate my java applet to control a joystick.

So far i make the following steps:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg rsa -alias MyCert

keytool -certreq -alias MyCert

that generate a csr:

Enter keystore password:  *********
-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIBtjCCAR8CAQAwdjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxCzAJBgNVBAgTAkNBMRIwE
AYDVQQHEwlDdXBlcnRpbm8xGTAXBgNVBAoTEFN1biBNaWNyb3N5c3RlbX
MxFjAUBgNVBAsTDUphdmEgU29mdHdhcmUxEzARBgNVBAMTClN0YW5sZXk
gSG8wgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBALTgU8PovA4y59eb
oPjY65BwCSc/zPqtOZKJlaW4WP+UhmebE+T2Mho7P5zXjGf7elo3tV5uI
3vzgGfnhgpf73EoMow8EJhly4w/YsXKqeJEqqvNogzAD+qUv7Ld6dLOv0
CO5qvpmBAO6mfaI1XAgx/4xU/6009jVQe0TgIoocB5AgMBAAGgADANBgk
qhkiG9w0BAQQFAAOBgQAWmLrkifKiUYtd4ykhBtPWSwW/IKkgyfIuNMML
dF1DH8neSnXf3ZLI32f2yXvs7u3/xn6chnTXh4HYCJoGYOAbB3WNbAoQR
i6u6TLLOvgv9pMNUo6v1qB0xly1faizjimVYBwLhOenkA3Bw7S8UIVfdv
84cO9dFUGcr/Pfrl3GtQ==
-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

I Paste in CaCert account that gives-me a file.cer.

I try to import into keystore:

```
keytool -import -alias MyCert -file caCertResponse.cer
```

and gives me the following error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to establish chain from reply
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you checked http://wiki.cacert.org/CodesigningCert

How can I use my code signing certificate? (java example)

The code signing privilege can be added to the new email certificates you will obtain from the CAcert website.

Once you are approved, the next time you'll request an email certificate, you will find an option to include the code signing privilege.

see Richard Dallaway web start & cacert, freemail thawte code signing or better here http://www.crionics.com/products/opensource/faq/signFree.htm ( /!\ note : as of November 2009, thawte freemail program including free java codesigning has been discontinued.)

list the certificates in the keystore (replace jks for storetype and .ks as keystore)

keytool -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore keystore.p12
sign the jar file

jarsigner -storetype pkcs12 -keystore keystore.p12 pasta.jar "guillaume frederic romagny's root ca id #2"
sign the jar file with timestamping (make sure to keep the arguments in that order!)

jarsigner -storetype pkcs12 -keystore keystore.p12 -tsa "http://time.certum.pl/" pasta.jar "guillaume romagny's root ca id"
verify the signed jar

jarsigner -verbose -verify -certs pasta.jar

In addition for testing you might need to add the CACert certificates both in Java and Browser